# Getting android mobile number by default

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am designing an application where I don't want the user to have to enter the mobile number.  The application should be able to get the mobile number by default and the user should not be able to modify it.

So, what code should I use for that? Are there any system calls I should use?

Comment: What is "number by default"? Is it a special known by you number?

Comment: @sll just i want my mobile number to be displayed in a phonenumber box without user input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you talking about the **sim number** which is used in that device, here is how you can get it

```
TelephonyManager man =(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String number = man.getLine1Number();
```

and you would have permission listed in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

Comment: 'but friend i dont see any in this dev guide..just take a look   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Comment: [Look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29)

Comment: i looked into the guide friend...will your code get the mobile number or other services like cdma,gsm,nearby mobiles etc etc..can i get the code for getting the mobile number exactly

Answer (score 0):

```
TelephonyManager tManager =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tManager.getLine1Number();
```

also you need read phone state permission.

Comment: but friend i dont see any in this dev guide..just take a look   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Comment: even if you apply this in your eclipse then also you will get hint that is there any method or not?